# do I have to add captcha in all forms?

Tags: captcha

I want to know if I should I use Captcha for all forms in my website?
or there is some cases that require it?

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your users are already authenticated (logged in), it is indeed a very good idea to have a captcha on each form to limit the number of spam bot abuse you receive.

In some cases, it is still a good idea even when the users are logged in.